# How to pass a string into mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE people " .
"SET first_name = '$fname' , last_name = $lname , email = $email , " . 
"age = $age , cityids = $city , gender = $gender WHERE id = $Recedit" 
or die (mysql_error));
```

But the query does not run.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, you should not be using `mysql_*` commands. The are deprecated. You should witch to `PDO`. Second, I think you just have a syntax issue. Notice you have `'$fname'` but only `$lname`. You are missing the quotes of the values. If you used `PDO` you could use paramaterized queries, which would take care of this for you.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: You've got quotes around `first_name = '$fname'` but not the others.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to see if quotes did anything to either of them, none of them applied. Should have fixed this up and the error bit at the end.

Comment: @EricLeschinski No error message.

Comment: Plus this `WHERE id = $Recedit` should have quotes around it. `WHERE id = '$Recedit'`

Comment: This example is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should never trust any user entered/submitted data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Have a look into using the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) php extension instead of mysql. One feature you may find handy is prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL query is incorrectly formatted. The `or die` should be *after* the query.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE people SET first_name = '$fname' , last_name = $lname , email = $email , age = $age , cityids = $city , gender = $gender WHERE id = $Recedit") or die (mysql_error);
```

But also, for readability, I recommend you do something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE people SET"
       . " first_name = '" . $fname . "',"
       . " last_name = " . $lname . ","
       . " email = " . $email . ","
       . " age = " . $age . ","
       . " cityids = " . $city . ","
       . " gender = " . $gender
       . " WHERE id = " . $Recedit;

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);
```

Formatting queries so they are human readable always helps you in the log run when debugging logic & formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the "... or die" thing out of the brackets.  Right now you're making a logical "or" between the string itself and the "die" command. Also, mysql_error is a function, so:

```
// WRONG
mysql_query("..............." or die(mysql_error))

// RIGHT
mysql_query("...............") or die(mysql_error())
```

Maybe there's something else too but this is surely a mistake.

Comment: the function's still deprecated.

Comment: That's not the point now. A non-deprecated function would behave just the same in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sorted out everything else that's wrong/out-of-date, your query might look something like this...

```
UPDATE people 
   SET first_name = '$fname' 
     , last_name =  '$lname' 
     , email = '$email' 
     , age = $age 
     , cityids = $city 
     , gender = '$gender'
 WHERE id = $Recedit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to

**1.** Write the simplest code. like this:

```
$concat_query = "upate ...
$result = mysql_query($concat_query);
if ($result) {
   if ((mysql_num_rows($result) ) > 0) {
     ...
```

**2.** Use Notepad++ to see pieces of code in different colors.

**3.** First execute the dbcode on database and later on write the code.